# Redirect abc.com to www.abc.com in opencart through .htaccess file in different folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have installed opencart in two folders - one is root folder i.e. 'public_html/' and one is 'public_html/test/'. Both opencart contains .htaccess files.

The .htaccess file of opencart on 'public_html/' folder contains following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /new/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.co\.in
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abcd.co.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and the .htaccess file of opencart on 'public_html/test/' folder contains following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /new/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is When i open Domain **http://abcd.co.in** it will redirect to **http://www.abcd.co.in**, but when i open **http://abcd.co.in/test**

> *it is not redirecting*

me to **http://www.abcd.co.in/test**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You hit the URL

```
http://abcd.co.in/test/
```

the `.htaccess` file from `public_html` root folder is not taken into count if You have another `.htaccess` file in the `public_html/test/` folder. You should extend the `public_html/test/.htaccess` this way:

```
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /new/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.co\.in/test/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abcd.co.in/test/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: It's not strictly true that the `.htaccess` isn't taken into account. It is read since `.htaccess` files above the directory get applied too however since the `RewriteBase` isn't correct it doesn't get applied in this case. This is the correct fix however so +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection rule is not applied. Also `.htaccess` should be limited to the folder your associated it too, try this, top of my head:

```
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /test/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /test/index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```